# Empty Json result executing Action Class using struts 2

Tags: java, json, struts2

Im trying to retrieve data from DB using hibernate ORM and get the out-put as json result using struts 2.Everything work up to retrieving data from DB.But for the json result I get only **{}**. I think I have done something wrong with my coding. But need some help to figure it out. Thanks.

> Here is my Action class :

```
 @ParentPackage("json-default")
public class SocialIconsAction extends ActionSupport {

    private List<TiendayaCurrencies> _currency;

    public List<TiendayaCurrencies> getCurrency() {
        return _currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(List<TiendayaCurrencies> _currency) {
        this._currency = _currency;
    }

    @Action(value = "currencies", results = {
        @Result(name = "success", type = "json", params = {"includeProperties",
            "_currency\\[\\d+\\]\\..*"})})
    @Override
    public String execute() {
        _currency = loadCurrencies();

        /*Nothing wrong with the DB results.Just to  test everything works fine.*/
        //for (TiendayaCurrencies _currency1 : _currency) {
           // System.out.println("Title - "+_currency1.getTitle());
       // }


        return SUCCESS;
    }

    private List<TiendayaCurrencies> loadCurrencies() {
        Session session = com.tiendaya.connection.HibernateUtil.
                getSessionFactory().openSession();
        List<TiendayaCurrencies> cList = session.
                createCriteria(TiendayaCurrencies.class).list();

        return cList;
    }
}
```

> Pojo class:

```
public class TiendayaCurrencies{


     private Integer id;
     private String title;
     private String code;
     private String symbolLeft;
     private String symbolRight;
     private char decimalPlace;
     ...
```

Is there anything wrong with the **includeProperties**?(Only place I can think of..) Can any one suggest a way.. I 've tried everything...